# Cómo ocultar la URL en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Si alguien accede a una URL, directamente o mediante otra URL y no una página principal de referencia, no se lo permite, por ejemplo:

Página principal: http://mydom.com

URL para acceder = http://mydom.com/user.html,
entonces

En la página principal:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>
{window.location.href = "http://mydom.com/user.html?access=true";});
```

En la URL user.html:

```
if((new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("acess") === true)) {
 document.innerHTML = " " ;
}
```

Ahora bien, pero, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que el `access=true`, no se vea en la URL como POST en PHP?

Comment: No se puede, por eso se están las llamadas post a un servidor, para ocultar esos datos de la url

Comment: Un truco *horrible* (tanto que no lo pondré como respuesta) es tener un iframe ocupando todo con la URL que quieres. En el navegador sólo se muestra la URL de la página principal

Comment: He leído que se puede con la API historial o cambiandolo a hash, pero no entiendo mucho

Comment: creo que eso se puede hacer por medio de API historial, API routers, usando localstorage(muy buena opción), el iframe(que dice @Pablo Lozano, aunque es _horrible_, como dice él).

Comment: No entiendo la solución de pablo, cómo el iframe lo cambiaría?

Comment: Olvídala, es una mala solución ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una solución simple es que la página, al cargarse, reescriba lo que aparece en la barra de direcciones.

```
window.history.replaceState({},'','user.html');
```

Esta respuesta está inspirada en el comentario de @CristianAgudelo